# При попытке сериализировать в память MemoryStream слишком быстро умирает

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация

Имеется код :

```
public class MemorySerializer
{
    static MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    public static void Serializer(object item)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, item);
    }

    public static object Deserialize()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Все было решено =))
Оказывается (до этого я не знал =)) что обьект в котором я использовал наш класс каждый раз пересоздается и использовать в качестве хранилища память не возможно =))
Пришлось использовать в качестве хранилища IsolatedStorage

Answer (score 5):

Этот код имеет ряд очевидных недостатков:

1. Поле `ms` и методы `Serialize` и `Deserialize` объявлены статическими, что делает бессмысленным создание экземпляров класса `MemorySerializer`;
2. Методы сериализации и десериализации создают экземпляр `BinaryFormatter` при каждом вызове, что несколько затратно;
3. Ошибка в коде: при десериализации происходит попытка чтения из конца потока.

Для их устранения стоит:

- Убрать спецификаторы `static`;
- Добавить конструктор, в котором следует производить однократное создание `BinaryFormatter`;
- Исправить ошибку: добавить перемещение к началу `MemoryStream` при десериализации (документацию по классу можно прочитать на MSDN).

Также рекомендую обратить внимание на *потенциальные* ошибки в коде: что будет, если вызвать `Serialize` дважды (или ни одного раза), а затем вызвать `Deserialize`?

Comment: Спасибо, будем решать =))
Получается, лучше создавать обьект ?
Методом Seek перемещать указатель на начало потока ?
Попытка не удалась =)) 
Видимо при запросе к MVC приложению каждый раз создается экземпляр контроллера который в свою очередь создает мой обьект с дефолтным обьектом =((